# Flask SQLAlchemy login with postgresql

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, python-3.5, flask-login

So I have already created a database using the pgadmin3 in postgresql. I have a set of email-ids and passwords. The passwords which I have stored are hashed, i.e. by using `pwd_context.hash(password)` from the `pass.libs`.
I have stored them as shown below in the database. Now I have to create another login form in html to authenticate. I am new to flask, but I have seen something called as flask-login. How to compare the password entered in cleartext with the hashed password in database.

[image]

Comment: Usually you'd hash a given password and compare, or your library in use would.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flask-login provides a set of functions... for user login,logout and so on. More information on Flask-login can be found at https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/.

For creating and checking a password hash: When working with Flask often werkzeug security is used to create/hash and check passwords. A snippet in which this is demonstrated can be found here : http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/54/

Finally an internet search (I have not used any of these tutorial/pages before) retrieved following page: https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/two-factor-authentication-with-flask with a quick browse of the page I found an example of using flask-login and werkzeug for user-login/logout under the title 'The First Factor: Password Authentication'. A quick pointer when using this tutorial is that there have been some changes in naming since the page has come online. For example flask.ext.login has been renamed to flask_login. The tutorial http://blog.sampingchuang.com/setup-user-authentication-in-flask/ also provides more information on flask-login and werkzeug. The pointer on renaming is also valid for this one.